# Pop up doesn't show me the photo I want

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, var, modalpopup

Problem with 'Classes' and GetElementById?

As you can see in my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/tta1eu/pen/gyGwOm), there are some photo in the Gallery section, when you click on someone of that, there is a pop up shows up, i need to open each different photo in that pop up when you click on that, and some info about the product, near the photo on the pop up, I think there is a problem in the Var on JS, I have to name the classes of the photo from child 1 to child 15?

I don't understand where the problem is

```js
window.onload=function(){

  var selectable = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
  for(var i = 0, j = selectable.length; i < j; i++) {
    selectable[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
  });
  }


  document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
   document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
  });


}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Mono');




body {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
  background-color: #000000;
height: 100%;

}

.header{
 height: 100vh;
  color: #f1f1f1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 background-size: cover;
 justify-content: center;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 25rem;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: center;
  display: inline-block ;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #66ff66;
  color: black;
}

#logo-container img {
   width:40%;
   height: auto;
   float: center;
}



.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: center;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

#Livello_1_copia{
right: 0; bottom: 10rem; top: 2rem;
min-width: 100%; min-height:100%;
width: auto; height: auto;
z-index: 100;
background: repeat;
background-size: cover;

display: block;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 color: whitesmoke;
}


.svg{
  fill:#ffffff;
  padding-top: 15rem;
  top: 20rem;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 800;
}

/*OVERLAY_Box-container della galleria*/
.overlays {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 5px;
  top: 25rem;
  right: 5rem;
  left: 5rem;
  align-items: center;
  margin:7%;
}

div.child:hover {
  cursor: crosshair;
}


/*Parent*/
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  top: 30rem;
  padding-top: 0rem;
  z-index: 50;


}

/*Child=Figlio del genitore= contenitore sigole foto*/
.child {
  flex: 1 0 20%; /* explanation below */
  margin: 6px;
  height: flex;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  align-self: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/*Img del figlio*/
.child img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: flex;
   margin: 0;
   bottom: 10rem;
   border-radius: 6px;
   margin-bottom: 6px;

}

.overlay p {
  font-size:1vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:  #00ff00;
}

.child .overlay {
margin-bottom: -40px;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black see-through */
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
     transition: .30s ease;
  opacity:0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;

}

#Avatar:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}

#Avatar1:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar2:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar3:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar4:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar5:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar6:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar7:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar8:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar9:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar10:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar11:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar12:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar13:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar14:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
#Avatar15:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}


/*OVERBOX TESTO IMG*/
.overbox {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 30vh;
  height: 24vh;
  padding: 130px 20px;
  flex: 1 0 20%; /* explanation below */
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 6px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.child:hover .overbox { opacity:50; }
.child .overtext {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
}

.child .title {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 50%;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.child:hover .title,
.child:focus .title {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
}

.child .tagline {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.child:hover .tagline,
.child:focus .tagline {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(20px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
}

/* - fine . OVERBOX TESTO IMG*/


#videogallery{
  top: 10rem;
}

video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}


.footer {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   background-color:  #4CAF50;
   color: #ffffff;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: auto;
}

.bg-modal{
  width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(63,191,63,0.64);
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
}

.modal-content {
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;
 background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;

}

#fotopopup{
 width: 100%;
  }

  .close {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 10px;
 font-size: 42px;
 color: #333;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 cursor: pointer;
 &:hover {
  color: #666;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PINSTRIPE GRILLZ</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery\js\jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gallery\js\main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery\css/main.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  </head>
  <body class="body">

    <header>
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <div id="logo-container"><a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/FgJ2BYn/PINSTRIPE-Logo-Site.png" alt="PINSTRIPE-Logo-Site" border="0">
        </div>

                  <a href="gallery.html.html">Gallery</a>
                  <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                  <a href="about.html">About</a>
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">

          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
      </div>



    </header>

    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="videogallery">
          <source src="gallery\img\bg_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>


    <div class="overlays">

      <div class="child" id="Avatar15"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7SPJ5Jz/VL.jpg" alt="VL" border="0">
        <div class="overlay"><p>White&yellow gold snakes @maibunia</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar14"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7SPJ5Jz/VL.jpg" alt="VL" border="0">
        <div class="overlay"><p>@dg_bladee </p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar13"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7SPJ5Jz/VL.jpg" alt="VL" border="0">
        <div class="overlay"><p>xxxstxr</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar12"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7SPJ5Jz/VL.jpg" alt="VL" border="0">
        <div class="overlay"><p>@ziskasecuris</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar11"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7SPJ5Jz/VL.jpg" alt="VL" border="0">
        <div class="overlay"><p>LV fangs @lui.vi</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar10"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7SPJ5Jz/VL.jpg" alt="VL" border="0">
        <div class="overlay"><p>@prettypukee coin</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar9"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7SPJ5Jz/VL.jpg" alt="VL" border="0">
        <div class="overlay"><p>Black gold biohazard @freddy.boy_bstrd</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar8"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/7SPJ5Jz/VL.jpg" alt="VL" border="0">
        <div class="overlay"><p>Silver</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar7"><img src="gallery\img/skll.jpg" >
        <div class="overlay"><p>10x10 cobalt chrome</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar6"><img src="gallery\img/4.jpg" >
        <div class="overlay"><p>@dg_bladee</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar5"><img src="gallery\img/ggvlff.jpg" >
        <div class="overlay"><p>@imran_potato</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar4"><img src="gallery\img/spnet.jpg" >
        <div class="overlay"><p>Spiderweb</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar3"><img src="gallery\img/Evil.jpg" >
        <div class="overlay"><p>Evil / @yungsherman95</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar2"><img src="gallery\img/shrk.jpg" >
        <div class="overlay"><p>Razor shark teeth</p></div>
      </div>

      <div class="child" id="Avatar1"><img src="gallery\img/wirte.jpg" >
        <div class="overlay"><p>8 bottom Barbwire</p></div>
      </div>



    </div>

<div class="svg-container unclickable"  onclick="return false">
      <svg class="svg 1.1 svg-container" id="Livello_1_copia" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
    y="0px" viewBox="0 0 722.3 312.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 722.3 312.2; transform: scale(1,-1)" xml:space="preserve">
     <g>
    <path d="M39.1,297.4c9.7,6.6,19.3,7.9,25.2,7.9c3.3,0,5.5-0.4,5.7-0.4l3.2-0.6l-3-1.3c-0.8-0.3-18.3-8.1-12.7-26.3l0.9-2.8
     l-2.4,1.6c-5.3,3.6-10.8,4.7-15.7,2.9c-4.7-1.7-8.3-5.7-9.9-11.4l-0.4,0.1c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7c0.9-2.2,2.4-4.2,4.3-5.5
     c1-0.7,2-1.2,3.1-1.6c1.1-0.4,2.3-0.7,3.4-0.8c2.3-0.4,4.8-0.3,7.2-0.1l8.4,0.7l-7.9-2.6c-2.1-0.7-4.3-1.2-6.5-1.5
     c-2.2-0.2-4.5-0.2-6.7,0.2c-2.2,0.4-4.3,1.2-6.2,2.4c0,0,0,0,0,0V216c0,0,0,0,0,0c1.4,0.2,2.8,0.2,4.2-0.2c1.4-0.3,2.7-0.8,3.9-1.5
     c1.2-0.7,2.3-1.5,3.4-2.6l3.3-3.2l-4.4,1.6c-1.2,0.5-2.6,0.8-4,1c-1.4,0.2-2.8,0.1-4.1-0.3c-0.8-0.2-1.6-0.6-2.3-1V6.8
     c0,0-4.7,27.4-7.9,30.2L21,37.4v226C21,268.4,22.3,285.9,39.1,297.4z M23,38.3c2.6-3.2,3.4-6.6,4.3-11.5V208
     c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.6-0.9l-0.6-1c0.2,0.7,0.3,1.5,0.6,2.2c0.3,0.7,0.6,1.4,1.1,2v0.4h0.3
     c0.4,0.5,0.9,0.9,1.4,1.4l1,0.6c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.3,1.1,0.5c1.5,0.6,3.2,0.7,4.7,0.6c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c-0.9,0.5-1.8,1-2.8,1.4
     c-1.2,0.4-2.4,0.6-3.7,0.7c-1.3,0.1-2.6-0.2-3.9-0.5c0.6,0.3,1.1,0.6,1.8,0.9v43.4h0.5c-1.1,1.1-1.9,2.5-2.2,4c0.7-1.7,1.9-3,3.4-4
     h0.3v-0.2c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.3c1.8-1,3.9-1.5,5.9-1.7c1.5-0.2,3.1-0.2,4.7-0.1c-1.2,0.2-2.3,0.6-3.5,1c-1.2,0.5-2.4,1.2-3.4,2
     c-2.1,1.7-3.5,4-4.3,6.5c-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.9-0.3,1.4l-0.5,0.1c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.3,1c-0.2,1.7-0.2,3.4,0.1,5c0-1.3,0.1-2.5,0.4-3.8
     c2.1,5.1,5.8,8.9,10.4,10.5c4.5,1.6,9.6,1.1,14.4-1.4l-2.1,2.9l-1.3,0.9c-7.6,5.8-18.1-0.1-18.2-0.2l-3.6-2l2.3,3.5
     c8.7,13.4,24.5,16.6,25.1,16.7l4.3,0.8L57,299c-0.3-0.2-6.9-5.3-4.8-15.2l0.2-1l2.2-3.1c-2.1,12.9,7,20.4,11.8,23.5
     c-5.1,0.3-15.7-0.2-26.3-7.4c-16-10.9-17.2-27.6-17.2-32.4V38.3z M53.2,297.8c-4.5-1.5-12.4-4.9-18.2-11.9c3.7,1.3,9.6,2.5,15-0.3
     C49.4,291.3,51.4,295.4,53.2,297.8z"/>
   </g>
  </svg>

  <svg class="svg 1.1 svg-container" id="Livello_1_copia" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
 y="0px" viewBox="0 0 722.3 312.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 722.3 312.2;transform: scale(-1,-1)" xml:space="preserve">
 <g>
  <path d="M39.1,297.4c9.7,6.6,19.3,7.9,25.2,7.9c3.3,0,5.5-0.4,5.7-0.4l3.2-0.6l-3-1.3c-0.8-0.3-18.3-8.1-12.7-26.3l0.9-2.8
   l-2.4,1.6c-5.3,3.6-10.8,4.7-15.7,2.9c-4.7-1.7-8.3-5.7-9.9-11.4l-0.4,0.1c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.3-0.7c0.9-2.2,2.4-4.2,4.3-5.5
   c1-0.7,2-1.2,3.1-1.6c1.1-0.4,2.3-0.7,3.4-0.8c2.3-0.4,4.8-0.3,7.2-0.1l8.4,0.7l-7.9-2.6c-2.1-0.7-4.3-1.2-6.5-1.5
   c-2.2-0.2-4.5-0.2-6.7,0.2c-2.2,0.4-4.3,1.2-6.2,2.4c0,0,0,0,0,0V216c0,0,0,0,0,0c1.4,0.2,2.8,0.2,4.2-0.2c1.4-0.3,2.7-0.8,3.9-1.5
   c1.2-0.7,2.3-1.5,3.4-2.6l3.3-3.2l-4.4,1.6c-1.2,0.5-2.6,0.8-4,1c-1.4,0.2-2.8,0.1-4.1-0.3c-0.8-0.2-1.6-0.6-2.3-1V6.8
   c0,0-4.7,27.4-7.9,30.2L21,37.4v226C21,268.4,22.3,285.9,39.1,297.4z M23,38.3c2.6-3.2,3.4-6.6,4.3-11.5V208
   c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.6-0.6-0.9l-0.6-1c0.2,0.7,0.3,1.5,0.6,2.2c0.3,0.7,0.6,1.4,1.1,2v0.4h0.3
   c0.4,0.5,0.9,0.9,1.4,1.4l1,0.6c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.3,1.1,0.5c1.5,0.6,3.2,0.7,4.7,0.6c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0c-0.9,0.5-1.8,1-2.8,1.4
   c-1.2,0.4-2.4,0.6-3.7,0.7c-1.3,0.1-2.6-0.2-3.9-0.5c0.6,0.3,1.1,0.6,1.8,0.9v43.4h0.5c-1.1,1.1-1.9,2.5-2.2,4c0.7-1.7,1.9-3,3.4-4
   h0.3v-0.2c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.3c1.8-1,3.9-1.5,5.9-1.7c1.5-0.2,3.1-0.2,4.7-0.1c-1.2,0.2-2.3,0.6-3.5,1c-1.2,0.5-2.4,1.2-3.4,2
   c-2.1,1.7-3.5,4-4.3,6.5c-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.9-0.3,1.4l-0.5,0.1c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.7,0.3,1c-0.2,1.7-0.2,3.4,0.1,5c0-1.3,0.1-2.5,0.4-3.8
   c2.1,5.1,5.8,8.9,10.4,10.5c4.5,1.6,9.6,1.1,14.4-1.4l-2.1,2.9l-1.3,0.9c-7.6,5.8-18.1-0.1-18.2-0.2l-3.6-2l2.3,3.5
   c8.7,13.4,24.5,16.6,25.1,16.7l4.3,0.8L57,299c-0.3-0.2-6.9-5.3-4.8-15.2l0.2-1l2.2-3.1c-2.1,12.9,7,20.4,11.8,23.5
   c-5.1,0.3-15.7-0.2-26.3-7.4c-16-10.9-17.2-27.6-17.2-32.4V38.3z M53.2,297.8c-4.5-1.5-12.4-4.9-18.2-11.9c3.7,1.3,9.6,2.5,15-0.3
   C49.4,291.3,51.4,295.4,53.2,297.8z"/>
 </g>
</svg>

</div>


<div class="footer">
  <p>© PinStripe Custom Jewelery .</p>
</div>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
    </script>

<!-- Modal Section -->

<div class="bg-modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="close">+</div>
   <img src="" alt="" id="fotopopup">
 </div>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55776386/edit) then the `[<>]` snippet editor and post the example here with expected output. We want a [mcve] and not reams and reams of CSS

Comment: OK ! im new here too, sorry , i m going to fix it!

Comment: @mplungjan it's ok now? u can run the snippet and see what i'm talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the image from the clicked element and pass it as the `src` of your element inside the popup like this :

```
window.onload=function(){

  var selectable = document.getElementsByClassName('child');
  for(var i = 0, j = selectable.length; i < j; i++) {
    selectable[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {

      document.getElementById('fotopopup').setAttribute('src', e.target.attributes['src'].value);
      document.querySelector('#text-block').innerHTML = e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
  });
  }


  document.querySelector('.close').addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "none";
  });


}
```

HTML of modal

```
<div class="bg-modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="close">+</div>
   <img src="" alt="" id="fotopopup">

   <span id="text-block"></span>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Live demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BEVpBZ)

Comment: Nice! i don't know the setAttribute, im new in coding and young new lil baby in Javascript! im going to read about it! Nice solution. how would you do instead to also show some info depending on the product you click?

Comment: Put a span with  an ID and copy text from for example a data-attribute or from class `overlay ` into it

Comment: yes, you can do that as @mplungjan mentionned, if you want to display the next sibling you can get that content too and display it, i'll add that into the answer.

Comment: Oh yes, it's beautifull, i can't wait to manage all the JS content and options! Thanks guys, what if the text on the pop up it's another text info, not the one you see when the mouse is over the img? @AbdelkarimELAMEL

Comment: you can put whatever you want (from a DOM element or something hardcoded, or a javascript variable), i've took the example of the text displayed after hovering for example. you can customize that to your needs.